# Should I use a cache for this?

Tags: javascript, caching

I made a code this summer holidays and today I look for the first time at my code again, and I am strugging on one thing I did.

My system is a system with multiple types (pages, newsletters etc.) and multiple subtypes (items, archive, concepts etc.). The idea now I have an object like this:

```
object { 1: { normal: { 1: { content: 'somecontent', title: 'sometitle' } } } }
```

Another example:

```
object { 1: { normal: { 1: { content: 'somecontent', title: 'sometitle' } }, archive: {} }, 2: { normal: {} } }
```

The data originally comes from the database. I'm making a system to edit pages on the website and other things like newsletters. Because I have multiple types and subtypes.

I made a cache for the reason I don't want to get all items from the database every time. But now the problem is if I add an item, edit an item and remove an item I have to delete it from the cache / edit / add.

My question: is this a good way? I thought it is because you don't have to call an AJAX file to get the data from the database.

I'm sorry if I'm not allowed to ask this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question: is this a good way? I thought it is because you don't
>   have to call an AJAX file to get the data from the database.

The answer is that "it depends".  There is no always right and always wrong answer for caching because caching is a tradeoff between efficiency and timeliness of data.

If you want maximum efficiency, you cache like crazy, but your data may not be perfectly up to date because you're using old data from the cache.

If you want the most up-to-date data, you don't cache anything so you always get the latest data, but obviously efficiency may suffer if you are regular requesting the same data over and over.

So, it's a tradeoff and the tradeoff depends entirely upon the application, its needs, how often the data is modified and what the consequences are for having stale data or for not caching.  There is no single right or wrong answer for that tradeoff.  It depends entirely upon the particular situation for your application and the tradeoff may even be different for some types of data vs. others within the same application.

For example, let's supposed you were writing an online bidding site that offered some functionality like eBay.  You would probably be fine caching the item description for at least several hours because that almost never changes and even if it does, the consequences of being a bit tardy on seeing a new item description are fairly low.  But, you could never cache the data on the current bid because the timeliness of that information is critical.   The user needs to always see the latest info on the current bid, even if you have to make some sacrifices in efficiency.

---

Also, remember that caching isn't completely all or none.  You can set a lifetime for a cached value such that it can only be used for a certain period of time that is appropriate for the type of data. For example, you might cache an item description in the above auction for up to 2 hours.  This allows you to achieve some efficiency gains, but also to eventually see the new data if it happens to change.

---

In general, you have to review the consequences of showing stale data.  If the consequences for having data that is even minutes out of date are high (like the latest price in a live auction), then you can't cache that data at all.

If the consequences of having data that is even hours out of date are low, then you can likely cache that value for at least several hours - maybe even longer.

And, when considering what to cache, you obviously want to first look at the items that are most requested and are the most expensive on your server to retrieve.  Some analysis of the usage pattern on your server would give you a prioritized list of candidates to consider for caching.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out for me. I didn't think of more than 1 possible answer!

Answer (score 1):

> My question: is this a good way? I thought it is because you don't
>   have to call an AJAX file to get the data from the database.

This is **fine** if

1) You want to provide **offline reading continuity** to the user. User doesn't have to wait for internet connection to be available so that they can read at any time.

2) Your **data-service is quite heavy** and you want to avoid multiple/frequent visits to the server to get the same data over and over again.

3) You want your app to be bundled with a native package (like phonegap) to become a **hybrid app** and give a complete offline experience to the user.

This is not a comprehensive list, but just to get your started in terms of when to go for offline and when to keep totally offline

So, on the other hand, this is a **bad** idea if

1) Your local storage structure is going to **change frequently** for user to require re-install (unless you can figure out auto-upgrate of local storage)

2) All your features are transactional and **require synch with other users** also.

Comment: Well the data updates if the user edits a item, which happens pretty often. Although, there is really much data in the database so getting around 500 items AND performing some other things such as building the array in PHP can take some time.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker does the data belong only to that user? does the updates have to immediately flow to other users in the system? These are the questions that govern your decision to use offline caching.

Comment: Well the cache does. The data gets updated/inserted/deleted in database and the changes you see on the website. This is just something on the CMS part of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your approach, just make sure you have kept these points in mind while managing client-side cache

1. You have one variable 'version' maintained, this version is to be increased whenever there's any change in structure, this version will be sent to client every time, client is responsible for comparison of versions and empty client cache if server version is greater than client version.
2. You can implement or find any open-sources to handle your ajax responses,  this one might be useful - https://github.com/SaneMethod/jquery-ajax-localstorage-cache.
3. you can set proper expiry tag from server, which can also help, browser to cache response for you, if it is 'get' request.
4. You can also implement server-side cache, which will not make calls to database, it will cache response against request-url, Note -  if different users are supposed to receive different response than this approach wont work. You can delete the cache if any changes happens related to that particular data set - delete/update
5. In your case you can also maintain flags on server, which simply tells if data has been updated or not the time of article update, if stored version is older you can make server-request or just use local version.

I hope it helps.